# Graphql Codegen giving name `CreateWithdrawLinkDocument` is defined multiple times error

Tags: next.js, graphql, codegen

I have setup Graphql codegen with next.js/react and ran the codegen file which generated code for typescript types however when I treed running my next.js application it gave
`` name `MySomeDocument` is defined multiple times ``
error.

this is my codegen cofig file

```
import type { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: [
    "http://1/api/graphql",
    "https://2/graphql",
  ],

  documents: ["./utils/graphql/*.ts"],
  generates: {
    "./utils/generated/": {
      preset: "client",
      plugins: [
        "typescript",
        "typescript-operations",
        "typescript-react-apollo",
      ],
    },
    "./graphql.schema.json": {
      plugins: ["introspection"],
    },
  },
};

export default config.
```

I have 3 files separate.
I tried to remove preset file but then I started getting this when I ran codegen

```
    ✖ Plugin "typescript-react-apollo" validation failed:

                Plugin "typescript-react-apollo" requires extension to be ".ts" or ".tsx"!
```

with preset is generating code perfectly but I am getting error in Next.js

how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by changing path from **./utils/generated/**  to **./utils/generated/graphql.ts**

Comment: Where is this updated exactly?